# Efficient Nuxt generated static site hosting: Better on Amazon AWS or a Cloud Droplet

Tags: amazon-s3, nuxt.js, hosting, aws-amplify, static-pages

not sure if it belongs here or is well titled, but I finish soon my first Nuxt project and I am not sure, where to host it.

Usually I would use a Ionos or digital ocean droplet, but I was told that aws amplify or S3 (I have no Idea about any solution) might be cheaper or maybe cost nothing, since it is a small project, cause it depends on how intense process are ...

If true, would that apply as well, when I would need to run git pull and then the build/generate process, once a day, to get new content (via nuxt/content)?

Sorry if expressed poorly and thanks in advance for any helpful suggestion.

Comment: Half. Cause I would like to know, how much performance this workflow would create and kinda cost with amazon.
Netlify and Vercel are neat, but to costly for my project. I guess I just try it out with amazon and see for myself.
But thanks a lot, for the suggestions.

Comment: AWS is not really optimized for JAMstack. As for cost, Netlify/Vercel are free for a variety of use cases. And it handles a lot of heavy lifting for you and have a great ecosystem for an awesome DX.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the reply.
In my case it would not be for free, that's why, I wanna seek out other options, better then having a droplet at Digital Ocean.

Comment: What will be outscaled and hence, not free?

Comment: Commercial use. I wrote both of my intention and they answered, it is not being covered by the free/community plan.

Comment: It's also essentially if you can delegate it to some serverless solution. Depending of the scaling needed, it can be independent of the host platform.

Answer (score 0):

This question do not really belong to stackoverflow because it's essentially opinion based.

By order of preference, I do personally recommend those:

- [Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/)
- [Vercel](https://vercel.com)
- [Digitalocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/products/app-platform/)
- [Github pages](https://pages.github.com/)
- [Surge](https://surge.sh/)

More on the official documentation of Nuxt: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/deployment/netlify-deployment